# Django: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: django, postgresql

I try to add some array like in the example

```
tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200),default=list)
```

I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: malformed array literal: ""
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

using `postgresql_psycopg2`...

Comment: try to change `blank=True` to be `null=True`.

Comment: @SergeyPugach `ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200),null=True,default=list)` does not work. :/

Comment: Can you post the code that's assigning to the `tags` array field?

Comment: I just added this to my model and did a `makemigrations` and then `migrate`...
Right now I'm doing nothing with this entry.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Comment: So are you getting the error when you run `migrate`, or when you submit a form? What action are you performing that generates the error?

Comment: I get this error when I'm doing a `migrate`.

Comment: I think your default should be a function returning `[""]` so there's an empty string in your array. You can't have an empty array. You can have no default if `null=True` in which case you'd better also have `blank=True`.

Comment: Could you provide me the code I have to use?
I'm very new into django stuff...

Comment: I know this is an old question but after getting the same error I added `ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True), default=list, size=50, null=True, blank=True)` and I deleted my migrations that were created and failing. I ran make-migrations again and migrate worked.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error and I think the key is to **delete the failed migrations** as @nullable has pointed out.

I tried:

```py
tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True), default=list)
```

And after deleting the failed migrations I was able to `makemigrations` and `migrate`. There seems to be no need to specify `size`, `blank`, or `null`.

[Document Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)

Btw in your database there's a table called *django_migrations* where you can find the last successful migration.

Comment: To show last successful migration: `python manage.py showmigrations --plan`

Answer (score 0):

```
topic_ids = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True), default=list)
```

After deleting the old migrations, re-execute

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you were converting a field of one type into a field of another type which was what I was doing, I believe the issue was that Django wasn't able to migrate the previous default value fields or any of the previous value fields.

My solution (since my field was unimportant) was that I deleted the field, made the migration to remove it, then brought back the field with the `ArrayField` type and then made the migration then. Everything appears to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a migration to delete any existing field, and execute that migration. After that create a new migration to Add `ArrayField`, Altering field causes a data type validation error on existing db objects.